# IONIC APP - Remove top bar on ion-modal-view

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, fullscreen

I've just finished to set-up my new ionic-angularjs app. I only need to do one more thing.

What I need is to simulate a full-screen call view (like the native one). 
To do that I'm now using a `<ion-modal-view hide-nav-bar="true" hide-back-button="true">` (modal view). As you can see, i've already added the attribute `hide-nav-bar="true"`, but it does not work.

How can I remove top bar from my modal view?

Any help would be very appreciated

Thanks,

Fra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ion-modal-view>` does not have a nav bar by default. I don't know what you are trying to hide if you have not added it already.

A modal without a header would solve your problem in think. Something like this

```
<ion-modal-view>
  <ion-content></ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

Comment: I've resolved my issue just trying to build the app. Seems to be a ionic serve problem. 
My HTML structure was exactly like your, but there was a nav bar in the screen.

By the way, it was only a ionic serve error. In the definitive app the nav bar does not exist. 

Thanks for your help. 
Cheers!